# MoveIt setup assistant not loading meshes; unable to find package name within the ROS workspace

Tags: urdf, moveit, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I have exported a hand SolidWorks assembly file into a URDF using a the sw_urdf SolidWorks addon. I have defined the joint tree and wanted to move onto setting it up fully using MoveIt setup assistant.
When I tried loading the file into it I have received the following error:

> ROS was unable to find the package name hand within the ROS workspace. This may cause issues later.

This is strange as I have followed this [guide](https://gist.github.com/RobinCPC/edb4c03d69b46d60be86ac0303a24437) when importing the generated URDF into my ROS workspace and it involved generating a package.

After I click OK to carry on and load the URDF into the setup assistant I get the following errors for every link I have (the example provided is a sample):

> [rospack] Error: package 'hand.urdf' not found
> [librospack]: error while executing command
> [ERROR] [1646655128.321427916]: Could not load resource [package://hand.urdf/meshes/palm.STL]: Unable to open file "package://hand.urdf/meshes/palm.STL".

It seems that because MoveIt did not spot the package directory it couldn't find the meshes directory. I am unsure how to resolve this issue as I did setup a ROS package using catkin_create_pkg command.

I will be very grateful if someone could guide me regarding this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397188/moveit-setup-assistant-not-loading-meshes;-unable-to-find-package-name-within-the-ros-workspace/) by [Zero1d](https://answers.ros.org/users/93796/zero1d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before opening the moveit assistance, you must source the workspace where your robot's description package is located.

Something like you have `~/catkin_ws/src/my_robot_description`

then,

to build your pkg, you can use `catkin_make` or `catkin build`.
after building the package, you must `source devel/setup.bash` before launching the moveit setup assistance from the same sourced terminal.

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2022-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero1d](https://answers.ros.org/users/93796/zero1d/) on 2022-03-13**:
In the end I just had to add the custom hand package to the MoveIt workspace. It's not as neat as I was hoping for since I wanted to apply MoveIt to multiple workspaces. Unfortunately I had to rebuild the whole of the MoveIt workspace. Maybe I'm missing something, but I just wasn't able to source two workspaces.